# Umbraco custom routes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, umbraco

I've just started developing in an Umbraco (v 7.3.4) project, and I can't seem to be able to set up custom routes. I've been going through many articles and other StackOverflow answers but I can't seem to find a clear and complete solution anywhere.

I have added a new controller called ReportingApi, inheriting from UmbracoApiController. The problem is that the route for it is:

```
http://myhostname.com/umbraco/api/reportingapi/{action}/{id}
```

However, I would like to have the following route:

```
http://myhostname.com/api/reporting/{action}/{token}/{id}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by extending `ApplicationEventHandler` and adding your custom routes there:

```
public class MyApplicationEventHanlder : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    public MyApplicationEventHanlder()
    {
        //Create a custom route
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "api",
            url: "api/reporting/{action}/{token}/{id}",
            defaults: new 
            { 
                controller = "Reporting", 
                action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            }
    );

    RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute routing. Decorate your action method with -

```
[Route("api/reporting/{action}/{token}/{id}")]
```

Also, check in the `WebApiConfig` file and make sure

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

code is present.

Comment: But... there's no WebApiConfig file in my project... Can I just add one? Will it not conflict with other Umbraco settings?

Comment: It also feels tedious to add the [Route()] attribute to every action. I'd rather declare one route configuration from the start (i.e. in WebApiConfig) and use that for this controller.

Comment: I added the WebApiConfig.cs file and wired it up in Global.asax, with the config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() instruction, and added the route attributes to my actions. It works! I would like to know if there's a way to just set the routing directly from WebApiConfig.cs (and work with Umbraco) and I'll accept your answer, because right now it still feels like an incomplete solution.